# Facebook like button fetching wrong information

Tags: facebook, button, dns, facebook-like

So I've recently registered a domain at my local domain registration service and I've made a campaign with a facebook like button.

The problem is that when I like my own page (click the facebook like button), the like button partly fetch information from the registration service homepage (title and content but not the URL).

I've check that my domain has propagated correctly and I bought it and fixed the DNS server settings days ago.

This is my page: http://saloonen.nu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange... It works for me. I liked you page, and on my FB profile, it shows url correct... Or i dont understand your question?

Next thing, why do you have 2 xmlns:fb="..." attributes in you html element?

Use FB debuger for issues like yourown http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Another thing, validate you html ;-) > http://validator.w3.org/ > too bad HTML isn't strict programming language ;-)

## EDIT

I found the problem, it is your content-type meta tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="uft-8">
```

it should be :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: I really didn't know what I was looking for but your answers put me in the right direction. As it seems the facebook web linter picks up information about my domain registration service website and not my own.

Facebook debuger says this: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=saloonen.nu


I still don't understand why

Comment: Well I used it but all I could see (apparently I'm blind) was warnings/errors of none-existing tags(according to the validator) and such that FB uses to integrate the like-button.